# How to find out what program is listing to port 80 on windows?

Tags: apache, windows-services, xampp, port, netstat

I am having issue when attempting to start XAMPP on port 80 because port 80 is being used by another service.

I don't want to change the default port to XAMPP. I need to find out what service is using port 80 and stop it.

I tried this command

> netstat -anb

But it did not give me any valuable info

Here is the port 80 related info that I got

```
Active Connections

      Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
      TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
     Can not obtain ownership information
      TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING
     Can not obtain ownership information
```

I also tried

> netstat -aon

which gave me a pid=4 for the line that is using port 80.
I tried to kill it using

> taskkill /pid 4

but I get this error even when running cmd as Admin.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>taskkill /pid 4
ERROR: The process with PID 4 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

I change the port that Skype uses so it is no longer using port 80.

How can I find out what service is using port 80?

Previously I had AppServ running on my laptop but I uninstalled it. I am not sure if this is still an issue.

Comment: Run `netstat -p...` as root.

Comment: @starblue I am using the command line as Admin. What is the full command that I should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that http.sys (kernel based) is a single system service that listens on the all-important port 0.0.0.0:80. Http.sys acts as a mediator to allow that multiple applications can receive http requests from port 80 based on the requested Url's.

The problem is that certain applications (example Apache http server) do not utilize http.sys API and tries to bind directly to port 80, causing it to fail since it is already in used by http.sys.

You can disable http.sys but that may affect other applications sharing port 80 via http.sys. Easiest will be to change your application's port to something other than 80, but as you mentioned it is not an option for you.

Another solution is to bind port 80 to your IPv6 general address (::) which will unbind your IPv4 address, allowing your application to bind to port 80 via the IPv4 address.

Run the following command to bind http to IPv6:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
```